# Preserve column names when converting the results of a query to hstore

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, hstore

I have a table `users` with columns `user_id`, `user_name` and `user_phone` for example.

If I do:

```
select hstore(u) from users u
```

the result is:

```
"user_id" => "1", "user_name" => "McEnroe", "user_phone" => "xxx"
```

If I do:

```
select hstore(u) from (select user_id, user_name, user_phone from users) u
```

the result is:

```
"f1" => "1", "f2" => "McEnroe", "f3" => "xxx"
```

I lose the name of the columns.
How can I use the 2nd example and having the correct column name?

Comment: what version of postgresql do you using? just tested on 9.2 and it works ok

Comment: For the general public: same problem applies to **json** with PostgreSQL < 9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a shortcoming that was **fixed with Postgres 9.2**.
I quote the [release notes for 9.2 here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-2.html#AEN111373):

> ### E.5.3.3. Queries
>
> (...)
>
> - Retain column names at run time for row expressions (Andrew Dunstan, Tom Lane)
>
>   This change allows better results when a row value is converted to hstore or json type: the fields of the resulting value will now have
>     the expected names.

<sub>Also, don't use `user` as table name, even if it's just a demo. It is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in every SQL standard and in Postgres and cannot be used as table name without double-quoting. I took the liberty to fix the test case in the Q.</sub>